# Java 'finally' clause in a nested 'try' block

Tags: java, exception

Will the following **finally** clause be executed, if an exception is thrown by the **PrintWriter**?

```java
try{
   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filename);
   try {
       //output
   } finally {
       out.close();
   }
} catch {
   //handle exception
}
```

If the **PrintWriter** throws an exception, then the nested **try** block will never get executed, but why the nested **finally** clause will still be executed, even it's nested and skipped?

**Updates:**
I ran some tests, if an exception is thrown before the nested **try** clause, that nested **finally** will not be executed. 
If the exception is thrown inside the nested **try** clause, then the inner **finally** and the outter **catch** will be executed.

Comment: That `finally` block is not related to your print writer statement

Comment: You should take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html btw.

Comment: `PrintWriter implements AutoCloseable` and therefore, you can just use a `try` with resources like `try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filename)) { ... } catch { ... }` where no `finally` will be needed (for `out`). What's inside the inner `try` that could throw an `Exception`?

Comment: it will in fact NOT be executed, but the inevitable application crash will cause the operating system to close the file (if it were even created)...

Answer (score 4):

No because the inner try block will not be reached when an exception occurs before and therefore the finally block is not reached either.

Answer (score 1):

**Finally block** is always executed whether exception is handled or not. Even though their is an error and it reaches to catch block, it will go to finally block to execute the piece of code.

> finally block is a block that is used to execute important code such
>   as closing connection, stream etc.

So, Inside try{} block you placed try and finally, but you asked about the catch of outside try ,thus its not going inside the first try block.That finally wont work.

P.S. : If you put finally something like this:

```
     try{
          try{...}
          finally{...}
        }catch(Exception e){...}
        finally{... }
//in case of exception also , the outside finally is going to work.
```

P.S.: Though you got your answer , but the concept is for reference of other naive programmers

Answer (score 0):

An uglier variant (sometimes generated by the IDE) one sees also:

```
// *** UGLY
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new PrintWriter(filename);
    //output
} catch (IOException e) {
    //handle exception
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // IGNORE
        }
    }
}
```

That explains the code a bit: as `close` may throw an IOException too, the code becomes cumbersome. Your code still needs nested exceptions.

With try-with-resources this can & should be written as:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filename)) {
    //output
} catch (IOException e) {
    //handle exception
} // Automatically closes.
```

And no longer nested exceptions.

The biggest advantage is that you need not catch any exception, and just add a `throws IOException` in the method signature.